# How to change the load path in Octave

Tags: octave

I have a problem with loading images and editing scripts in Octave. I think Octave has the wrong path or something. When I say 'edit', it says:

> sh: 1: emacs: not found

What does that mean?

I'm pretty new to both Octave and MATLAB, but when I'm at school using MATLAB, for example, writing the command 'edit' works...

How do I know where to put files I want to load in Octave, and how do I change the path?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your path, the problem is that you didn't set up `EDITOR` (see `help EDITOR` and the editor option at `help edit`). As you have no environmental variable for it, it defaults to emacs so when you run `edit`, it tries to open the file in emacs and fails because you don't have it installed. Set up `EDITOR` for your text editor of choice at `.octaverc` file (If I remember correctly, the text editor to use is set as a persistent variable inside `edit.m` so you'll have to restart octave) or an environmental variable (I'd recommend this one).

It works in matlab because they made their own text editor. Octave is not a text editor, it's a programming language, it would be a waste of time to reinvent the wheel, and you should be able to choose whatever you are comfortable to code with.

Comment: ok, thanks! so I can choose any editor? Then what command do I use, for example if I want to use the editor 'gedit' ? I found this: getenv("EDITOR") and this: VAL = EDITOR (). am I on the right track? Tried them but don't know if i did it the right way, and nothing seemed to happen..

Comment: As I said, there's two ways. Environmental variables are valid for all applications, and are therefore independent of Octave. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables to read about envioronmental variables and how to set it. That's my recommendation (you shouldn't need to use `getenv`, for the case of EDITOR, Octave will do that for you). The alternative is to run `EDITOR gedit` at the start of each Octave session (use `.octaverc` instead).